# How to perform conditional segue

Tags: swift, segue, swift3, ios10, xcode8

I've created a segue through IB. When buttonA is clicked, a transition to viewB will occur.

In the button click action, I have `performSegue(withIdentifier:sender:)` wrapped in a condition. I want the segue to occur only if the condition is true.

However, once the user clicks the button, the segue happens before the condition is even run. What is the best way to transition programmatically while still using segue identifiers defined in IB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have created segue from the `UIButton` to a `viewController` that is the reason segue happens before the execution of condition. Instead of that remove that segue from storyboard and create another from your `ViewController` to `DestinationViewController`.