# PerformSegueWithIdentifier in Swift 3

Tags: navigation, swift3, segue, xcode8, ios10

When I click button, On satisfying some condition, I need to go from view controller 'A' to view controller 'B'. So if condition is satisfied i am writing in that if block

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "fistBump", sender: self)
```

but irrespective of condition (if the condition is not met also) it is navigating to 'B' view controller.

I gave segue('fistBump') from View Controller 'A' to navigation controller scene(not to 'B' scene) in storyboard for my other purposes.

Comment: Please don't deface your post by rolling back our improvements.

Comment: please show us some more code. Also, did u check if have not hooked the segue into a button instead of the viewControllers?

Comment: Segue shouldnot be given from button you are saying, or?

Comment: no, it should be between to viewControllers. If it is hooked on a button, it will be fired no matter what. That is why it is going there, even when your condition fails.

Comment: It is working fine.Thank you so much.

Comment: i have added an answer with further explanation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to perform conditional segue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40002607/how-to-perform-conditional-segue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you are attaching the segue from a UI element to `ViewControllerB`, rather than directly from `ViewControllerA`.

Some cases, it makes sense. When you have no condition to evaluate, you can directly fire segue from UI elements.

However, when u would like to evaluate a condition, it is a better practice, if u attach the viewControllers with the segue, and fire the segue programatically, when your condition is evaluated. You need to drag from the yellow circle the segue to the target viewController, and name your segue.[image]