# How to use same segue for multiple buttons in iOS swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, segue

I've around 20 buttons in my iOS app which segue to the same UIViewController. It's a game written in Swift. To implement that, I created a segue in Storyboard for 1st button. For rest of the buttons I'm attaching them to the same IBAction method and calling the segue created above with it's ID. Problem with this approach is that for the 1st button application tries to perform segue 2 times and it throws an error in logs saying 
*UIView: 0x7f7fe9c84600; frame = (0 0; 320 568); autoresize = W+H; layer = CALayer: 0x7f7fe9c848d0>>'s window is not equal to TileGame.GameScreen: 0x7f7fe9dc6bc0>'s view's window!* It's not really a problem visible to use but I guess it's not the right way to do things. Plus, it's adding unnecessary logging.

Below is my code for IBAction

```
@IBAction func action(_ sender: Any) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueToSecondScreen", sender: self)
}
```

Does anybody have suggestion on how to deal with this issue? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: May be you are having same problem like this. http://stackoverflow.com/q/40002607/6433023

Comment: Use manual segue and connect all IBActions to same method

Comment: Hi guys, thanks a lot for help. @Arasuvel's answer below solved my problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of creating a segue for the button. You can create for `ViewController`.

**Step1:**
[image]

**Step2:**
[image]

**Step3:**
[image]

Give the name for segue and use this one all button actions.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This worked fine. Earlier also I thought there should be one and tried to do ctrl+drag from one view controller to another but looks like for view controller ctrl+drag works in the menu list on the left side and not inside the actual storyboard. Anyway, problem solved. Thanks. :)

Comment: @hellSigma: That's great.

Comment: You can do it in the Storyboard as well.  Control drag from the ViewController icon at the top of the from ViewController to the desired ViewController in the Storyboard.